# using Not in in SubQuery with not equal to

Tags: oracle, plsql, subquery

Following two queries are resulting into different number of records by interchanging the condition in following way:

```
select count(1) from clientlist where userid  
 not in (select distinct userid from Clientlist
    where userid in (select uniqueid from employee e where emplstatus = 'Y' ))
```

Returning 38885 number of records

```
select count(1) from clientlist where userid  
 in (select distinct userid from Clientlist
    where userid in (select uniqueid from employee e where emplstatus != 'Y' ))
```

Returning 3630 number of records

would any one please be able to explain what difference the change in condition is causing that much difference in results?

Comment: Could you give some sample data? Which part does return less rows, the inner or the second inner?

Comment: What are the possible values of `empstatus` other than `Y` ?

Comment: There is no interchanging in your conditions. If second internal query will return other list of users then first, than yes it will be, but as far as I see it won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Table ClientList      Table employee
  Id                    Id   Status
  --                    --   ------
  1                     1    Y 
  2                     2    N
  3                     3    null
  4
```

First query counts id's: `2`, `3`, `4` - rows which are in `ClientList` and are not in `employee` and marked as Y.

Second query: id `2` - shows rows which are in both tables and in table 2 are marked as 'N'.